# Changes to plymouth do not change bootanimation

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

I followed this [guide](https://github.com/eamileann/Ubuntu-boot-splash-colour-change) to change to boot animation (I just skipped step 5 since I only want to change the color). I can select the newly created boot animation after the command `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`.

Unfortunately there are no changes to my boot animation.
I tried to set the color to `1.00, 1.00, 1.00` and `0.00, 0.00, 0.00` to make sure that the color difference is nit to little to see. Still no changes.

**Thus my question is: how to set the new boot animation?**

I want to mention that I used grub-customizer to change my grub order. Maybe this affect the way I have to make the changes?

My system:
Ubuntu 18.04 (Kerel: 5.0.0-27-generic) on a Dell XPS 15

Comment: when you restart the system is it applied atleast to the shutdown time animation?

Comment: No. Not any change to either boot or shutdown animation.

Comment: when I tried in 2 systems.. 0ne w0rked f0r shutd0wn time.. 0ther worked f0r b0th.. I am just thinking what c0uld be the reas0n..

Comment: whats the output 0f `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` gives the following:
`There are 2 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).`
Below the following options are listed:
`0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo-nonpink/ubuntu-logo.plymouth   100       auto mode`
`* 1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo-nonpink/ubuntu-logo.plymouth   100       manual mode`
`2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth           100       manual mode`

Comment: So my newly added non-pink version is listed and selected.

Comment: yes.. can you also share the code part which you said 1 1 1 and 0 0 0.. what is the actual produced at boot animation time?

Comment: I have set it to 0.17 0.17 0.17 again since this is the target color I want.
`Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.17, 0.17, 0.17);`
`Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.17, 0.17, 0.17);`

Comment: what is the actual color you are seeing at boot time??

Comment: The default pink of Ubuntu boot animation.

Comment: I have just followed all the steps from the link you provided.. but changed the directory names like this and it is working where previously it worked only for shutdown time animation..  https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9a5U.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the script path in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth` did not change to the path to the correct animation script, so my changes to the script did not take action.

What it was:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=Ubuntu Logo NonPink
Description=A theme that features a blank background with a logo.
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo-nonpink
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

Changed the last line to:

```
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo-nonpink/ubuntu-logo.script
```

fixed the problem.